# Drawing text on canvas appropriately

Tags: android

I am try to draw text and bitmap images in my app. I would like the text to be drawn above the bitmap icons but am having difficulties in achieving that.

How do i modify or change my code so it displays at the top of each icon [image: Screen shot of the app notice the text is behind the icon]

my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);



    xCanvas = canvas.getWidth();
    yCanvas = canvas.getHeight();



    Paint textPaint2 = new Paint();
    textPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    textPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    textPaint2.setTextSize(30);
    textPaint2.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);


    destination = new Location("manual");

    for (int j = 0; j < placesListItems.size(); j++){
        song = placesListItems.get(j);

        this.lat = myLat.get(j);
        this.lng = myLng.get(j);
        this.name=song.get(KEY_NAME);

        try {
            this.icon = ICON.get(j);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  Log.d("the latitude",(String.valueOf(this.lat)));
        //  Log.d("the longitude",(String.valueOf(this.lng)));
        // Double.parseDouble(song.get(KEY_LNG));



        destination.setLatitude(this.lat);
        destination.setLongitude(this.lng);




        //Log.d("Place name",name );

        this.location.distanceTo(destination);

        // compute rotation matrix
        float rotation[] = new float[9];
        float identity[] = new float[9];
        if (lastAccelerometer != null && lastCompass != null) {
            boolean gotRotation = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation,
                    identity, lastAccelerometer, lastCompass);
            if (gotRotation) {
                float cameraRotation[] = new float[9];
                // remap such that the camera is pointing straight down the
                // Y
                // axis
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotation,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z,
                        cameraRotation);

                // orientation vector
                orientation = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(cameraRotation, orientation);

                canvas.save();

                // Translate, but normalize for the FOV of the camera --
                // basically, pixels per degree, times degrees == pixels
                float dx = (float) ((canvas.getWidth() / horizontalFOV) * (Math
                        .toDegrees(orientation[0]) - this.location
                        .bearingTo(destination)));
                float dy = (float) ((canvas.getHeight() / verticalFOV) * Math
                        .toDegrees(orientation[1]));


                // wait to translate the dx so the horizon doesn't get
                // pushed off
                canvas.translate(0.0f, 0.0f - dy);


                // now translate the dx
                canvas.translate(0.0f - dx, 0.0f);

                canvas.drawText((truncate(this.name,10).concat("...")), canvas.getWidth()/2 - 50, canvas.getHeight() / 2 - 100,
                        textPaint2);

                canvas.drawBitmap(icon, canvas.getWidth()/2 - icon.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2 - icon.getHeight()/2, null);

                canvas.restore();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to get hold of metrics for the font you're using. You can do this using

```
Paint.FontMetrics fm = textPaint2.getFontMetrics();
int fontHeight = fm.bottom - fm.top;
```

(tweaked to use bottom and top which seem to be more accurate)

You can then adjust the vertical location based on the real text size (rather than using arbitrary numbers)

Suppose you have an icon that you want to paint with two lines of text above it (a label and the coordinates), and you want the icon centered at x, y. The following example demonstrates this.

NOTE: You allocate Paint objects inside your draw method - this is really a bad idea, as the objects are always the same and just end up kicking off the garbage collector. A lot. Allocate the once and reuse. I demonstrate this as well.

I draw the crossed lines to point at the target x,y values; you won't need them, but it helps show exactly where the target is relative to the icon and text.

```
package com.javadude.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Paint.FontMetrics;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    public static class MyView extends View {    
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        private Paint textPaint;
        private Paint linePaint;
        private Drawable drawable;
        private float textHeight;
        private float baselineOffset;

        private void drawIconAndText(Canvas canvas, int centerX, int centerY, Drawable drawable, String text) {

            // draw the drawable centered on (targetXcenter, targetYcenter)
            int w = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();            
            int h = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            // determine upper-left corner of drawable location
            int x = centerX - w/2;
            int y = centerY - h/2;

            // draw the icon
            drawable.setBounds(x, y, x+w, y+h);
            drawable.draw(canvas);

            float textY = y - baselineOffset;

            // note that drawText centers the text at the given location due to Align.CENTER
            canvas.drawText(text, centerX, textY, textPaint);

            // if you had used Align.LEFT, you would need to offset the start of the text as follows:
            //     float textWidth = textPaint.measureText(text);
            //     canvas.drawText(text, centerX - textWidth/2, textY, textPaint);

            // draw the coordinates above it
            textY = textY - textHeight; // move up a line
            canvas.drawText("(" + centerX + "," + centerY + ")", centerX, textY, textPaint);
        }

        private void initPaint() {
            linePaint = new Paint();
            linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            linePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            textPaint = new Paint();
            textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
            textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            textPaint.setTextSize(30);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = textPaint.getFontMetrics();
            baselineOffset = fontMetrics.bottom; 
                // bottom is the maximum amount that the text descends
                // I'm not sure why this is different from descent...  
            textHeight = fontMetrics.bottom - fontMetrics.top;
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            int width = canvas.getWidth();
            int height = canvas.getHeight();

            int targetXcenter = width/2;
            int targetYcenter = height/2;

            // only allocate objects once it at all possible!
            if (textPaint == null)
                initPaint();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK); // draw background

            // draw lines to show where the target is
            canvas.drawLine(0, targetYcenter, width-1, targetYcenter, linePaint);
            canvas.drawLine(targetXcenter, 0, targetXcenter, height-1, linePaint);

            drawIconAndText(canvas, targetXcenter, targetYcenter, drawable, "Sample Text");

            // draw lines to show where the target is
            canvas.drawLine(0, 200, width-1, 200, linePaint);
            canvas.drawLine(100, 0, 100, height-1, linePaint);

            drawIconAndText(canvas, 100, 200, drawable, "More Text");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more please